# NDSolve::ndsz: At t == -96804.6, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I am trying to solve these equations but couldn't figure out how to solve the NDSolve::ndsz error.

```
NDSolve[
{-(1/4) (f3')[t]^2-1/2 (f3')[t] (f4')[t]-3/4 (f4')[t]^2+(3 ((f3')[t]+2 (f4')[t]))/(2 t)-(f3'')[t]/2-(f4'')[t]==0,
1/2 (f3')[t]^2-(f3')[t] (f4')[t]-3/4 (f4')[t]^2+(3 (f3')[t]+4 (f4')[t])/t-(f3'')[t]-(f4'')[t]==0,
f3[-100000]==20,f4[-100000]==20,f3[1000]==12,f4[1000]==12},
{f3[t],f4[t]},{t,-100000,-1000}]
```

Can anybody please look into this about what I am missing here?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does the solution computed show a singularity in one of the functions or their derivatives?

Comment: This is a [frequently asked question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=NDSolve%3A%3Andsz).  It seems that a Q&A with generic advice might be helpful. There are at least two possible problems, the two indicated by the message, plus `WorkingPrecision` as a possible third.  It's worth remarking how rarely someone has looked into which of the two, singularity and stiffness, seems to be the problem.  Some advice on how to do that might be helpful.